# Float Argument must be a string or argument in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, typeerror, pyspark, k-means, rdd

I want to apply k means clustering on PySpark.
However I get type error: float() argument must be a string or a number. Is there anybody who could immediately help me?

```
lines = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
new = lines.map(lambda x: (str(x[2]), str(x[3]), str(x[4]), str(x[5]), str(x[6])))
new.take(4)

Sample input (new):

[('-13', '7', '-0.573824415813', '0', '1'),
 ('-20', '13', '-0.728721307165', '0', '1'),
 ('-27', '14', '-1.18661648046', '0', '1'),
 ('-29', '10', '-0.757241996939', '0', '1')]    

k = 10 # cluster size for k-means
kmeans_iteration = 40000
estimator = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=k, n_init=10)
estimator.fit(new)
```

Comment: You should explain more!

Comment: Since my x[4] variable is float, I have this error. However, I am giving str or int while defining x[4]. But I am going to have same error. Although I have removed x[4] from the input, and all other inputs are integer,  again I have the same error. @AlbertoBonsanto

Comment: Why does your code look so different from [the Spark MLLib example code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#k-means)? Why aren't you using numpy arrrays?

Comment: I am using RDD @KatyaHandler. How I can use numpy arrays?

Comment: If you look at the inputs in [the Spark MLLib example code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#k-means), each row is a numpy array. From the link: `parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([float(x) for x in line.split(' ')]))`

Comment: I would also add that I don't understand this at all: `estimator = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=k, n_init=10)`. That looks an awful lot like the [sklearn implementation of KMeans clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). Again, you should be using the [Spark MLLib implementation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#k-means) implementation of KMeans clustering, as that operates on RDDs. SKlearn will not operate on RDDs.